# I have created a counter throught jQuery but is start working as soon as i load the page i want to execute it when the section appear on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

code for counter but it start working after page is loaded i want to work it when the section is visiable:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var counters = $(".counter");
var countersQuantity = counters.length;
var counter = [];

for (i = 0; i < countersQuantity; i++) {
counter[i] = parseInt(counters[i].innerHTML);
}

var count = function(start, value, id) {
var localStart = start;
setInterval(function() {
if (localStart < value) {
localStart++;
counters[id].innerHTML = localStart;
}
}, 80);
}
for (j = 0; j < countersQuantity; j++) {
count(0, counter[j], j);
}
});
```

Comment: Please, summarise in the title of question only the main question, not whole description.
Also, please, fix your grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$(document).ready(function() {` will run the callback only after the initial DOM has fully loaded. On a large page, this may be some time after the initial elements are visible to the user.

Make sure jQuery is included above (maybe in the `<head>`), then after the final `.counter` element in the HTML, put in a script tag immediately, so that it runs as soon as the element is created in the DOM, without waiting for the rest of the page to load:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div class="counter">100</div>
<div class="counter">200</div>
<div class="counter">300</div>
<div class="counter">400</div>
<script>
var counters = $(".counter");
var countersQuantity = counters.length;
var counter = [];

for (i = 0; i < countersQuantity; i++) {
  counter[i] = parseInt(counters[i].innerHTML);
}

var count = function(start, value, id) {
  var localStart = start;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (localStart < value) {
      localStart++;
      counters[id].innerHTML = localStart;
    }
  }, 80);
}
for (j = 0; j < countersQuantity; j++) {
  count(0, counter[j], j);
}
</script>
<div>content</div>
```

Note that you can significantly clean up your code, if you wish, and there's no need to require a big library like jQuery just to select elements:

```html
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div class="counter">100</div>
<div class="counter">200</div>
<div class="counter">300</div>
<div class="counter">400</div>
<script>
for (const counter of document.querySelectorAll('.counter')) {
  const target = Number(counter.textContent);
  counter.textContent = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const curr = Number(counter.textContent);
    if (curr < target) counter.textContent = curr + 1;
    else clearInterval(interval);
  }, 80);
}
</script>
<div>content</div>
```